# how to groupby a Multi Index time series data?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

Say I generate a df as below

```
testdf = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4,4),index= pd.date_range("20170101",periods=4),columns =list("ABCD"))

testdf
Out[40]: 
                   A         B         C         D
2017-01-01  0.084624 -0.371352 -1.013843 -1.102199
2017-01-02  0.390855 -0.519623  0.241092 -1.474969
2017-01-03  0.129163 -0.183547 -1.333859 -0.864320
2017-01-04  1.265360 -0.260505  0.633058 -0.077758
```

I then create a mulit-index as below

```
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([list("ABCD"),("one","one","two","two")],names=['letter','number'])

testdf.columns = index

testdf
Out[44]: 
letter             A         B         C         D
number           one       one       two       two
2017-01-01  0.084624 -0.371352 -1.013843 -1.102199
2017-01-02  0.390855 -0.519623  0.241092 -1.474969
2017-01-03  0.129163 -0.183547 -1.333859 -0.864320
2017-01-04  1.265360 -0.260505  0.633058 -0.077758
```

Now how can I group by `number` ?

I tried to group as below.

```
testdf.groupby('number')
```

which throws the error below.

```
KeyError: 'number'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with parameter `axis=1` for group by columns, define level and then add aggregate function like `sum`, `mean`:

```
df = testdf.groupby(axis=1, level=1).sum()
```

Or:

```
df = testdf.groupby(axis=1, level='number').sum()
```